# Permanent fix for Opencv videocapture

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

This question has been posed numerous times on many websites, but not definitive solution. I am trying to run Opencv with a video using function:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
if(cap.isOpened()==False):
print "Error opening camera"
```

But it fails every time. I have tried almost all steps from various sites, but couldn't get it to work (including rebuilding ffmpeg separately).

Any help would be much appreciated.

My platform is Ubuntu17 and Python3.

Comment: Was a fix on github. Tried with Opencv, same issue.

Comment: @zindarod updated the code

Comment: @zindarod The 1st one - not built properly. I have looked at various pages to do so, any suggested links i can check out to build opencv with ffmpeg?

Comment: I faced the same issue.Putting complete path of the video starting from /home solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This answer is written with Linux and Python in mind, but the general idea can be applied to any OS and language supported by OpenCV.

The `VideoCapture` class not opening the video file can have many causes, but the following three applies to most cases.

### OpenCV FFMPEG support:

By default OpenCV uses ffmpeg to read video files. OpenCV may not have been built with FFMPEG support. To find out if OpenCV was built with FFMPEG support, in terminal enter:

```
python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i ffmpeg
```

The output should be something like:

> FFMPEG:                      YES

If the output is `No` then follow an online guide to build OpenCV from source with ffmpeg support.

### FFMPEG Codec:

It's possible that FFMPEG does not have codec for your specific file. We are going to use [this video](http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/grb_2.mp4) as an example, to show if FFMPEG has decoding capability for this file.

First, we need to find the encoding format used in this video file. We will be using the `mediainfo` program. In terminal, enter:

```
mediainfo video_file.mp4
```

In the output, under the *video* heading, look for *format*. In this case the video encoding used is *AVC*, which is another name for H264.

[image: pic]

Now, we try to find if FFMPEG supports codec for decoding *AVC* encoded files. In terminal:

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i avc
```

On my machine, the output is:

> DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_crystalhd h264_vdpau ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )

We are interested in *DEV*, which stands for Decoding, Encoding and Video. This means that *AVC* is a video encoding format and FFMPEG supports both encoding and decoding capabilities for this format.

### File PATH

Lastly, check if the file path is correct or even if the file exists.

Comment: I am working on fedora 26 and I have the same problem. In the first command , I get FFMPEG: No. How to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I followed
Steps from [Link](http://www.erogol.com/installing-opencv-3-2-anaconda-environment-ffmpeg-support/)

and

This Cmake command in above Link is as below which worked

cmake -DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON -DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON -DENABLE_AVX=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DWITH_IPP=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_EIGEN=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON -DWITH_VTK=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") -DPYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..

I am not well verse of OpenCV build but exact **PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python** path is which points I think the OpenCV bindings for particular python to get updated