# Compiled version of OpenCV is unable to read video metadata (frame count)

Tags: python, opencv, video, compilation, metadata

I have compiled `OpenCV` according to https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Used sources for `2.4.13.4`.

Used the following `cmake` command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.5m PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=/usr/include/python3.5 PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so 
PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include ..
```

Tests ran ok.

`sudo make install` ran ok.

Unfortunately, in Python:

```
    video = cv.VideoCapture(filename)
    frame_count = int(video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
```

returns zero.

Suspect that `cv2` package I use in python is just something separate.

How to ensure `cv2` uses the same OpenCV i compiled?

**UPDATE**

```
dims@calculon:~$ python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
3.3.0
dims@calculon:~$ pkg-config opencv --modversion
2.4.13.4
```

Comment: In terminal: `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"` and `pkg-config opencv --modversion`, check if the outputs are the same. If the `VideoCapture` class is not able to open video files then read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112642/permanent-fix-for-opencv-videocapture/47116576#47116576

Comment: results were not the same, see my update please

Comment: So your python install is running a different (newer) version than you are building.

Comment: @MartinBeckett okay, and how to force it to use one I am building?

Comment: Remove the other one from your packages (pip or conda)

Comment: @MartinBeckett how?