# Unable to read video file using cv2.VideoCapture() function in OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("1.mp4")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Its throwing error

> libv4l2: error getting capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: device 1.mp4: Unable to query number of channels
>   after compiling.

Comment: Is the driver for the camera installed properly. This is an error coming from the library who tries to access the camera via IOCtrl-calls to access the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112642/permanent-fix-for-opencv-videocapture/47116576#47116576

Comment: The driver is properly installed as i am able to access web camera by passing 0 in the cv2.VideoCapture() function.