# Opencv VideoCapture always returns false on Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm using the following code to open a video stream:

```
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture()
video.open("some_m3u8_link")
success, image = video.read()
```

However, even if the code works as intended locally, on Heroku `success` is always false.

I'm using cedar-14 stack with the following buildpacks:

> heroku/python
>
> https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git

(I tried several buildpack options for ffmpeg)

Running `ffmpeg --version` on heroku instance will return `ffmpeg version 4.0-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/`

Is there any setting/configuration I missed in order to make it work on deployment? Thank you!

Later edit: I tried several links for "some_m3u8_link" including from twitch and other streaming services (including traffic streaming li
An example for reproducing:

```
python -c "import cv2; video=cv2.VideoCapture(); video.open('https://hddn01.skylinewebcams.com/live.m3u8?a=5tm6kfqrhqbpblan9j5d4bmua4'); success, image = video.read(); print(success)"
```

Returns True on local machine and False on Heroku.

(the link is taken from [here](https://www.skylinewebcams.com/en/webcam/malta/malta/traffic/traffic-cam14.html))

Comment: Where does your **`some_m3u8_link`** point? To a local file or to a web resource?

Comment: @Leon to a web resource

Comment: Can you then provide that link so that your code turns into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please provide the link as well as a minimal deployable repo

Comment: I tried with several links and the result is the same.

Comment: Can you perform [these tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116576/2286337) on Heroku? See what the results are.

Comment: Inspecting the file using a hex editor seems like there isn't a link in there... can you confirm this file works as you say it does?

Comment: @zindarod Thanks, opencv has been built with FFMPEG support

Comment: @JonathanMay You are right, the links I provided were not fit for this use case (The read seem to work if the link points to a static resource I think). I updated with a new link (a traffic camera video streaming which behaves as expected)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture("some_m3u8_link")
success, image = video.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use pafy module with cv2

-try opencv3 if its not working with cv2

```
    import cv2, pafy
    url = "Some url to stream"
    video = pafy.new(url)
    best = video.getbest(preftype="webm")
    video=cv2.VideoCapture(best.url)
```

- [pafyPYPI](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/)

Comment: As I see from pafy project description it seems to be designed to work on youtube only ("Retrieve YouTube content and metadata")

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the mode to open it might work.

```
video.open("some_m3u8_link", "r")
```

If that doesn't work then specifying the file extension might help.
You might also need to make a variable equal to the function

Ex:

```
""" replace .mp4 with the applicable file type, 
I don't know if you need to specify file mode"""
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture()
video = video.open("some_m3u8_link.mp4") 
success, image = video.read()
```

If this doesn't work then I am out of ideas.