# How to process VLC UDP stream over OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, udp, h.264, vlc

I was able to receive/view UDP h264 packets through VLC command line (i.e. VLC --network-caching 0 --demux h264 udp://...)

I am planning on processing those frames through OpenCV algorithms. However, I can't seem to find a way to send the VLC frames over to my Python OpenCV script.

Is it possible to pipe VLC stream output to be processed through Numpy in a separate script?

I have previously tried directly streaming to OpenCV by using its VideoCapture function, but for some reason, the video stalls and stops at a distorted black image. For now, it seems like incorporating VLC is the only solution (even though I am not totally sure why VLC works over other methods).

Thank you.

EDIT:

The following is a snippet of the error message on the terminal. It seems like there are problems with the first few frames, but I don't know why the stream works on VLC. From the client, I first sent a default key frame data, and then sent video feed h264 data.

```
[h264 @ 0x7f9c50020200] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x7f9c50020200] error while decoding MB 7 0, bytestream 7208
[h264 @ 0x7f9c50020200] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x7f9c50020200] error while decoding MB 8 9, bytestream 7381
```

Comment: What is your streaming server?

Comment: I am sending h264 data from an Android phone (acting as a client), which my computer receives through VLC command.

Comment: what video format do you want to use in OpenCV? `vlc` or `ffmpeg` can be used to change the video encoding format.

Comment: I've only worked with image formats for OpenCV, so I'm not really sure about how the video format would be used on OpenCV. Since it has to be real-time extraction of frames, I assumed the h264 data will be decoded into image frames, instead of through a video format.

Comment: vlc uses live555 which is open source. You could write your own live555 client and wrap it in a C library. Although I'm interested in whether there is a way to use vlc programmatically, too :)

Comment: @Micka VLC is built around [libVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/). Documentation [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=76751).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) for streaming.

First test ffmpeg streaming in terminal. In linux, we use `v4l2` to grab frames from camera.

**Server**:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f h264 udp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

**Client**:

```
ffplay udp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

If you're able to view the stream on the client side, then we can use OpenCV for image processing. OpenCV must have ffmepg support. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116576/2286337) for ffmpeg support check.

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://127.0.0.1:5000',cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print('VideoCapture not opened')
        exit(-1)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            print('frame empty')
            break

        cv2.imshow('image', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1)&0XFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried running ffplay command but the terminal says the command is not found. I have not tested VideoCapture with cv2.CAP_FFMPEG yet, but would it be possible that this is the reason why the OpenCV video capture did not work? I have tried googling on adding ffplay onto the ffmpeg installation, but I have not been successful as of now.

Comment: @J.S. You don't need `ffplay` to view stream. You can write it to file by: `ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:5000  ./out.mp4`.

Comment: When I tried with the bash command and VideoCapture with cv2.CAP_FFMPEG, they both stop at a distorted black image and crashes (same as what I described in the original post). I am still confused about why I can stream on VLC but not on FFMPEG. I have updated the original post with the error messages.

Comment: What about be the -f flag value for streaming from UDP? Also, why do you do ffmpeg on the Server and then ffplay on the Client?

Comment: Also, what version of OpenCV are you using?