# OpenCV: Illegal Instruction 4 when trying to instantiate VideoCapture with path

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have the following code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/full/path/to/video.mp4")
```

When I run it on MacOS 10.11.6 with Python 3.6 and 3.7, the program stops with the error message `Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)`.
The path is valid (checked using `os.path.isfile`) and opening the webcam stream with 
`VideoCapture(0)` doesn't throw an error.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116576/5008845

Comment: @Miki None of the solutions worked.

Comment: Downgrading to OpenCV 3.1.0.4 solved the problem.

Comment: When you try cap.Read (or somethin similar to grab frame) or on this line of code the program stops?

Comment: The program stops on this line.